# pentaho report designer: how to turn off text wrap option?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

On my report, all the fields have their fixed width and height and if the content is longer than the width, it automatically increases the height of field (like G3 on screenshot). But I want it looks like G2 on screenshot.
I turned off `text wrap` option, `dynamic height` to false. However it doesn't seem there's change.
Someone can help me please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the cell and set the option `Style` -> `size & position` -> `x-overflow` to `true`. This allows text to exceed the horizontal limit of its cell.